# Can't find huge memory leak in a Flex 4.6 web application

Tags: apache-flex, memory-leaks, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

I have [a Flex 4.6 web game](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/) which displays 2 Lists with virtual layouts with 2 custom item renderers. The renderers consist mainly of  BitmapImages displaying user avatars + few Labels.

[image]

The Lists are being updated often over TCP socket with gzipped JSON data. I [merge that data into 2 ArrayCollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736769/merge-data-into-filtered-arraycollection-maybe-by-using-iviewcursor-or-localind) serving as dataProviders for the Lists. This seems to work well, the Lists do not flicker and are updated correctly (I've monitored debug traces a lot to get it right).

```
{
    lobby: [
        "OK252342810632",
        "OK122471020773",
        "DE54",
        "DE6577",
        "DE7981",
        "OK225312168135",
        "OK20629248715",
        "DE7880",
    ],
    games: [
        { 0: [] },
        { 9012: [
            "VK48058967",
            "MR14315189992643135976",
            "OK10218913103",
        ] },
        { 9013: [
            "OK305894249541",
            "OK151358069597",
            "OK515549948434",
        ] },
        { 9007: [
            "OK366541092321",
            "DE7062",
            "OK122700338897",
        ] },
        { 8993: [
            "OK78476527766",
            "VK5692120"
        ] }
    ]
}
```

My problem is that the application gets sluggish very soon and for some users the plugin crashes and so the users complain a lot.

In the profiles I see this picture (memory jumps to 20 MB and stays there or sometimes jumps to 40MB etc.):

[image]

From profiler I can't figure out - what is leaking the memory. On the top I see **Vector.<*>** Class - whatever that means.

I've tried so many things already to fix this issue:

- Switched from native JSON.parse() back to com.brokenfunction.json.decodeJson() (because I thought maybe Adobe got it wrong)

  - I delete the JSON object after I've parsed it:

  private function handleTcpData(event:ProgressEvent):void {
      // read ByteArray over socket, unzip it - works well

  ```
  var obj:Object = decodeJson(_bytes.toString());

  // merge into 2 ArrayCollections, update GUI... works well?

  for (var key:String in obj)
      delete obj[key];
  obj = null;
  ```

  }

  - I've switched ContentCache off - makes no difference
  - I've stopped using any temp. Objects like **{ id: "DE22" }** and use the JSON Object directly

Does anybody please have a good advice?

I've read a lot of docs/blogs on AS3 garbage collection and the usual tips: set Object references to null, use weak event listeners, removeChild() does not free memory, etc. - but I don't see how to apply this to my problem.

Below is my complete **Lobby.mxml** source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:comps="*"
    width="700" height="450">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="_filter" change="handleRadio(event);" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Metadata> 
        [Event(name="game", type="PrefEvent")] 
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

            [Bindable]
            private var _games:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            [Bindable]
            private var _users:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            private function handleRadio(event:Event):void {
                switch (_filter.selection) {
                    case _allBtn:
                        _games.filterFunction = null; 
                        break;
                    case _vacBtn:
                        _games.filterFunction = vacantGame;
                        break;
                    case _fullBtn:
                        _games.filterFunction = fullGame;
                        break;
                }
                _games.refresh();
            }

            private function vacantGame(obj:Object):Boolean {
                for (var id:String in obj) {
                    var players:Array = obj[id];
                    return players.length < 3;
                }

                return false;
            }

            private function fullGame(obj:Object):Boolean {
                for (var id:String in obj) {
                    var players:Array = obj[id];
                    return players.length == 3;
                }

                return false;
            }

            // merge arrays of objects
            private function mergeObjs(ac:ArrayCollection, array:Array):void {
                var i:int;
                var j:int;
                var n:int;
                var src:Array = ac.source;

                // 1) remove items missing in data from _data
                FOUND1:
                for (i = src.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    for (j = array.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                        if (ObjectUtil.compare(src[i], array[j]) == 0)
                            continue FOUND1;
                    }

                    n = ac.getItemIndex(src[i]);
                    if (Util.DEBUG)
                        trace('REMOVED OBJ ' + src[i] + ' filtered n=' + n + ' i=' + i);

                    // remove visible items
                    if (n > -1)
                        ac.removeItemAt(n);
                    // remove hidden (filtered) items
                    else
                        src.splice(i, 1);
                }


                // 3) add items appeared in data to _data
                FOUND2:
                for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                    for (i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
                        if (ObjectUtil.compare(src[i], array[j]) == 0)
                            continue FOUND2;
                    }

                    if (Util.DEBUG) 
                        trace('ADDED OBJ ' + array[j] + ' i=' + i);

                    //ac.addItemAt(array[j], i);
                    ac.addItem(array[j]);
                }
            }

            // merge arrays of strings (the user ids)
            private function mergeIds(ac:ArrayCollection, array:Array):void {
                var i:int;
                var j:int;
                var n:int;
                var src:Array = ac.source;

                // 1) remove items missing in data from _data
                FOUND1:
                for (i = src.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    for (j = array.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                        if (i == j)
                            continue FOUND1;
                    }

                    n = ac.getItemIndex(src[i]);
                    if (Util.DEBUG)
                        trace('REMOVED ID ' + src[i] + ' filtered n=' + n + ' i=' + i);

                    // remove visible items
                    if (n > -1)
                        ac.removeItemAt(n);
                        // remove hidden (filtered) items
                    else
                        src.splice(i, 1);
                }


                // 3) add items appeared in data to _data
                FOUND2:
                for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                    for (i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
                        if (i == j)
                            continue FOUND2;
                    }

                    if (Util.DEBUG) 
                        trace('ADDED ID ' + array[j] + ' i=' + i);

                    ac.addItem(array[j]);
                }
            }

            public function update(games:Array, lobby:Array):void {
                var vac:uint = 0;
                var full:uint = 0;

                for each (var game:Object in games) {
                    for (var id:String in game) {
                        var players:Array = game[id];
                        if (!players)
                            continue;

                        if (players.length < 3)
                            vac++;
                        else if (players.length == 3)
                            full++;
                    }
                }

                if (games)
                    mergeObjs(_games, games);

                if (lobby)
                    mergeIds(_users, lobby);    

                _allBtn.label  = 'All ' + _games.source.length;
                _vacBtn.label  = 'Vacant ' + vac;
                _fullBtn.label = 'Full ' + full;
            }

            public function appendText(str:String):void {
                _chat.appendText(str);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="baseline" paddingLeft="8" paddingRight="8">
            <s:Label text="Игровые столы:" />
            <s:RadioButton id="_allBtn" group="{_filter}" label="Все" selected="true" />
            <s:RadioButton id="_vacBtn" group="{_filter}" label="Свободные" />
            <s:RadioButton id="_fullBtn" group="{_filter}" label="Полные" />
            <s:Spacer width="100%" />
            <s:Label text="Игроки в лобби: {_users.length}" />
        </s:HGroup>

        <mx:HDividedBox width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:List id="_gamesList" itemRenderer="Game" useVirtualLayout="true" dataProvider="{_games}" skinClass="PrefListSkin" width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="180">
                <s:layout>
                    <s:TileLayout />
                </s:layout>
            </s:List>

            <mx:VDividedBox width="180" height="100%" minWidth="180">
                <s:List id="_usersList" itemRenderer="User" useVirtualLayout="true" dataProvider="{_users}" skinClass="PrefListSkin" width="100%" height="100%" minHeight="150">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:TileLayout />
                    </s:layout>
                </s:List>   
                <s:TextArea id="_chat"  width="100%" height="100%" minHeight="40" editable="false" fontSize="14" color="#000000" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"/>
            </mx:VDividedBox>
        </mx:HDividedBox>

    </s:VGroup>
</s:Group>
```

**UPDATE:**

I must add, that my problem (users complain about reproducable Flash plugin crashes) has started after I have switched from XML to JSON.

I have re-run the Profiler and **why does it show 987 instances of the JSON.parseCore** while there are only 400 users in the Lobby (and only few currently visible in the Lists with virtual layouts)?

[image]

Any ideas please, what could have changed when I went from XML to JSON? (I didn't touch anyhting else). I was actually hoping for better performance, because I read about XML leaking memory in Flex sometimes...

Comment: At this point I would try two things. 1 elimination/reduction, that is remove chunks of the application one piece at time and see what action causes the memory leak based on deduction. 2 create or use an existing logger class that keeps track of the execution time and log messages at the beginning and end of every function, also output total memory. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#totalMemory

Comment: Check under the util package here I posted a logger that does what I explain above http://www.shaunhusain.com/DrawTextRandomly/srcview/

Comment: Also as cupuyc stated this doesn't appear to be a memory leak to me, I would expect to see in the profiler a consistently ascending line if it were, instead I just see the spike when something is loaded and then a flat line which would indicate memory is stable.

Comment: I'm not very proficient with Flash Builder Profiler: is it a flat line or do I just hit some Flash Player memory cap?

Comment: No you're not hitting an upper bounds in fact i have yet to see an upperbounds in flash applications and some of our apps consume 3-4 hundred megs of RAM, to be fair attempting to profile those is a bit ridiculous, but with any true memory leak u should see a steady rise over time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code and features look very simple. I don't think that memory leak is the case. Are you able to reproduce "sluggish" yourself?

I noticed that you have chat. If there will be a lot of text - application can work slow and crash at some moment. Be sure to limit chat to display only last 100 lines for example.

UPDATE:
Just visited your game and noticed that users have High Resolution Images as profile image. It could cause slowness as count grow.

Comment: Yes, the players use quite high resolutioned avatars/fotos... I wonder  how to improve performance there - I don't want to create any smallish bitmaps on the fly - because my game can be run in a full screen mode.

Comment: You could try to disable these image and check if game will run better.